# FPDF Output muestra pantalla en blanco

Tags: php, fpdf

Hola Tengo el muestreo de varios informes en una aplicación php con FPDF, hasta hace nada en el servidor en el que estaba dicha aplicación los pdfs se generaban de manera correcta, pero al migrar la misma a otro servidor diferente (el servidor no es mío es de un tercero, yo sólamente programe la aplicación) la función Output() me muestra la pantalla en blanco sin hacer nada, la cuestión es que al probarlo en el servidor local funciona correctamente, os dejo el código a continuación por si alguien encuentra algún error que yo no haya visto.

```
<?php
include_once 'app/configuration/config.inc.php';
include_once 'app/configuration/Conexion.inc.php';
include_once 'app/libraries/ControlSesion.inc.php';
include_once 'app/libraries/Redireccion.inc.php';
include_once 'app/libraries/EscritorContenido.inc.php';

if (!ControlSesion::sesionIniciada()) {
    Redireccion::redirigir('login.php');
}
include_once 'app/Beans/Vehiculo.inc.php';
include_once 'app/Beans/Cliente.inc.php';
include_once 'app/Beans/Logotipo.inc.php';
include_once 'app/Beans/Alquiler.inc.php';
include_once 'app/Models/Alquiler_model.inc.php';
include_once 'app/Models/Cliente_model.inc.php';
include_once 'app/Models/Vehiculo_model.inc.php';
include_once 'app/Models/Logotipo_model.inc.php';
include_once 'app/libraries/fpdf/fpdf.php';
Conexion::abrirConexion();
$arrayAlquileres = Alquiler_model::getAllIncidenciasImprimir(Conexion::getConexion());
Conexion::cerrarConexion();
if (count($arrayAlquileres)) {
    $pdf = new FPDF('L', 'pt', 'A4');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $numFilas = 0;
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 9);
    $pdf->Cell(90, 10, utf8_decode('Vehículo'), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(70, 10, utf8_decode('Matrícula'), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(50, 10, utf8_decode('Color'), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(120, 10, utf8_decode('Cliente'), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(80, 10, utf8_decode('Fecha de Entrega'), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(80, 10, utf8_decode('Fecha de Salida'), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(100, 10, utf8_decode('Teléfono'), 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->MultiCell(0, 10, 'Incidencias', 1, 'C');
    $totalAlquileres = 0;
    $totalKmRecorridos = 0;
    foreach ($arrayAlquileres as $alquiler) {
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
        $pdf->Cell(90, 10, utf8_decode($alquiler['vehiculo']->getModelo()), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(70, 10, utf8_decode($alquiler['vehiculo']->getMatricula()), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(50, 10, utf8_decode($alquiler['vehiculo']->getColor()), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(120, 10, utf8_decode($alquiler['cliente']->getNombre()), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(80, 10, utf8_decode(EscritorContenido::escribirFechaEspPdf($alquiler['alquiler']->getFecha_entrega())), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(80, 10, utf8_decode(EscritorContenido::escribirFechaEspPdf($alquiler['alquiler']->getFecha_salida())), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(100, 10, $alquiler['cliente']->getTelefono(), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->MultiCell(0, 10, utf8_decode($alquiler['alquiler']->getGestor()), 1, 'C');
        $numFilas++;
        if ($numFilas % 50 == 0) {
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 9);
            $pdf->Cell(90, 10, utf8_decode('Vehículo'), 1, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->Cell(70, 10, utf8_decode('Matrícula'), 1, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->Cell(50, 10, utf8_decode('Color'), 1, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->Cell(120, 10, utf8_decode('Cliente'), 1, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->Cell(80, 10, utf8_decode('Fecha de Entrega'), 1, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->Cell(80, 10, utf8_decode('Fecha de Salida'), 1, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->Cell(100, 10, utf8_decode('Teléfono'), 1, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->MultiCell(0, 10, 'Incidencias', 1, 'C');
        }
    }
    $pdf->Output();
} else {
    Redireccion::redirigir('alquileres.php');
}
```

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si la respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Hola me topé con el mismo error, en el server local funcionaba y en el server ya para verlo en la web me mostraba la pantalla en blanco, cualquier error que se tenga antes del `output()` eso pasará, el detalle es que la clase del `header()` muestra una imagen y yo había olvidado agregar la imagen en el servidor es por eso que no funcionaba, lo ideal es hacer el ejemplo más sencillo para ver si funciona y genera el PDF (sin mandar llamar la clase del `header` y `footer`), el ejemplo más simple es el siguiente (claro sin usar base de datos ni nada), aquí solo hay que tener un folder que se llame `fpdf` con los archivos y `subfolders` de esa librería.

Este es un ejemplo que yo hice para imprimir en una impresora de 58mm de ancho, impresora de tickets.

```php
<?php
    require 'fpdf/fpdf.php';
    
    $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(58,200));
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $pdf->Cell(40,6,'PRUEBA',1,0,'C',1);

    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que, si hay algún error en la ejecución del código o cualquier salida que no sea la gestionada por FPDF, el método `Output()` ya no genera correctamente el PDF.

Comenta la línea `$pdf->Output();` y comprueba si todos los métodos que invocas devuelven lo que tienen que devolver y no dan ningún mensaje Notice, Warning o Error.

Una vez que consigas ver la pantalla del navegador en blanco, ya podrás utilizar el método `Output()` para que muestre el PDF.

Por otra parte, entenderás que, con todas esas dependencias, poco podemos hacer desde aquí. Modifica la pregunta incluyendo un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que incluya lo mínimo para asegurarte de que todo lo relativo a FPDF funciona correctamente y puedas descartar que no se te haya olvidado subir a tu nuevo servidor algún fichero de los múltiples que incluyes. Con ese ejemplo MCV y el mensaje de error que obtengas, ya podremos ayudarte un poco más. Ánimo con ello.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ya soluciomné el problema, todo se debía a un problema con el servidor el cual me bloqueaba la opción de generar un pdf dinámico sin guardarlo, añadiendo la ruta de destino y el nombre de archivo el $pdf->Output();